# What do I need to do when moving out of Germany as a non-EU citizen?

Tags: germany, eu, relocation

After working in Germany as a non-EU citizen for 3 years I am moving to another EU country.

I already did the following:

- got de-registered from city-office
- cancelled my apartment contract

Is it enough or should I also do something else?

Comment: cancel all your contracts - phone, internet, insurance.. and also close your bank accounts.

Comment: What other things have you signed when you moved in? Health insurance? Electricity, gas (separate from your apartment contract)? Mobile phone? TV? Internet? Newspaper?

Comment: @Dirty, why would you close your bank accounts? That seems to me to be an unwise move unless you are sure you will never ever return and/or there are fees associated with keeping the account open and/or there are laws prohibiting having a bank account as a non-resident. Having a local account can be very useful for a variety of reasons.

Comment: @jmac usually there are fees if you keep the bank account open and don't deposit araound 1000 EUR every month

Comment: @Dirty, is that a Germany-specific thing? Or a bank-specific thing? If the latter, it may be better advice to suggest finding a no-fee bank to park your money in as it is exceedingly difficult to open a bank account as a non-resident (if possible at all) which will cause headaches on your return, and will prevent you from using a domestic bank (which can be helpful for a variety of things from paying local bills, to giving you a place to transfer earnings to your currency in).

Comment: @jmac I am not 100% sure, but I think that most banks have such fees, probably there are some banks that don't have it.

Comment: My bank would charge me 10 Euro a month if the incomes are less then 1500 Euro. From what I know, finding a bank without fees is very hard. I've tried to open a free internet-bank account, but they've simply ignored my application :o Never happened to me in Poland, I've opened 2 internet bank accounts as almost-no-money student.
As an EU-citizen I'll have to do the same things as OP. I hope I don't forget anything.

Comment: Just keep in mind that many banks *require* that you report any address change, so not reporting that you moved makes you break terms and conditions, and reporting address changes to non-german address may get your account closed.

Answer (score 3):

This [article](http://germany.angloinfo.com/moving/leaving/) provides detailed recommendations on the following topics:

- Housing Issues (ending a rental contract; selling a property; cancelling insurance)
  Disconnecting Utilities (notifying service providers to end/transfer your contract: electricity, gas, water, telephone and Internet)
- Health Care (updating social security and health insurance funds)
- Business and Tax (alerting banks and tax authorities of your departure)
- Vehicles and Driving (updating your car registration certificate; checking any driving licence issues)
- Alternative Considerations (informing the embassy and your local authorities; notifying schools; forwarding post; preparing your pets for travel)

Comment: The link is broken. Please fix it or update whatever is/was mentioned in it.